# Build dictionary from list of lists and maintain position of elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to build a dictionary from list of lists and want to maintain position.

I want to maintain in the dictionary as key the occurrence of the text
and for value it will be list of lists, which will contain at first
position the list where text came from and rest are the indices
of it in that list. If it appears in 2nd list then second list
and indices of it in 2nd list and so on etc.

This is my code:

```
    def make_dict(lists):
        my_dict = defaultdict(lambda:None)    
        for sublist in lists: 
            for i in range(len(sublist)):        
                if sublist[i] in my_dict: 
                    my_dict[sublist[i]].append(i) 
                else:           
                my_dict[sublist[i]] = [i]
        return my_dict
```

**Sample Input:**

```
    some_dict = make_dict([['d', 'e', 'f','d'], ['d', 'g','f']])

    print some_dict['d']

    print some_dict['e']

    print some_dict['g']
```

Sample Output:

```
    [[0,0,3],[1,0]]
```

d appears in first list (0) with indices 0 and 3 and then in 2nd list(1) with index 0.

```
    [[0,1]]
```

e appears in first list (0) with index 1

```
    [[1,1]]
```

g appears in 2nd list (1) with index 1

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def make_dict(seq):
    dic =  {}
    for i, lis in enumerate(seq):
        indices = {}
        for j, item in enumerate(lis):
            indices.setdefault(item, [i]).append(j)
        for k, v in indices.items():
            dic.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return dic

lis = [['d', 'e', 'f','d'], ['d', 'g','f']]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> my_dict = make_dict([['d', 'e', 'f','d'], ['d', 'g','f']])
>>> my_dict['d']
[[0, 0, 3], [1, 0]]
>>> my_dict['e']
[[0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i am checking it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this output

```
some_dict['d']
[[0,0,3],[1,0]]
```

Why not this output?

```
some_dict['d']
{0:[0,3],1:[0]}
```

This is doable with a `defaultdict` that gives you a `defaultdict(list)`:

```
def make_dict(nested_list):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

    for i,li in enumerate(nested_list):
        for j,c in enumerate(li):
            d[c][i].append(j)
    return d
```

demo

```
some_dict['d']
Out[12]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [0, 3], 1: [0]})

some_dict['e']
Out[13]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [1]})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to keep the text as keys for later use.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, sorry.  The text *is* keys.